# Configure an Openshift MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, replication, openshift

Tried to configure an openshift MongoDB Replica Set, so I configured the main openshift application instance, but when trying to add a new replica set member:

```
rsMeetPays:PRIMARY> rs.add('aaa.bbb.ccc:27017')
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't use localhost in repl set member names except when using it for all members",
    "code" : 13393,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I made a ping from openshit to the server aaa.bbb.ccc, so it exists an it is alive. When trying to resolve the server's name:

```
[app-gear.rhcloud.com user]\> nslookup aaa.bbb.ccc
nslookup: isc_socket_bind: permission denied
```

So, can I assume MongoDB can not resolve names, and thus there is no way to set up a MongoDB replica set on Openshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift currently doesn't support MongoDB Replica Sets. Please vote on the feature here:
https://www.openshift.com/content/support-replica-sets-for-mongodb